# permutation count for a k-length word in a language

Tags: permutations

Given an alphabet of A different letters, how many K length words can we form that have exactly D different letters?

The answer is given here:

[Permutations of fixed length words of an arbitrary alphabet with fixed number of different letters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433375/permutations-of-fixed-length-words-of-an-arbitrary-alphabet-with-fixed-number-of)

but, with my limited mathematical knowledge of the presented formula "the additive recursion from Marc van Leeuwen" , i see no possibility to calculate my problem.

**The example:**
 Alphabet = 18 letters. Permutations for a 3, 4,5, 6 letter word always has at least half of the letters consonants and the other letters are vowels. The vowels can be 4 or another number.

Comment: What happens if you look up the terms on the internet you do not understand?

Comment: I hoped Mathworld would provide a tool for the answer, but i could not locate it there as well. Do you have a link with the answer Moritz?